# What are the differences between sharing a dockerfile on git and sharing a docker container?

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile

When you create a private container on Docker, it seems to me that there are two viable options :

1 - create a private container

2 - sharing the dockerfile on a private git repository.

I'm not sure about which approach I have to chose depending on my usage, (maybe both ?), so I wanted to know if someone is interested about sharing his experience with the subject.

Comment: well, I think you're aware of the difference between a container and a dockerfile. Since opinion-based questions are off-topic on stackOverflow, you might need to re-phrase your question, or specify more clearly what you want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Both are effectively the same thing**

A **rough analogy** would be saying:

- Should I share my source code? or
- Should I share the compiled executable?

You can choose anything.. but if the end user isn't interested in modifying the source, you might as well **make it convenient for them** and just share the compiled executable.

Same goes for the dockerfile or the image created using the dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

A Dockerfile is use to create a docker image by issuing

```
docker build --tag xxx .
```

Notice it ends with . to pickup the Dockerfile from the current dir (you can also give the path to a Dockerfile ) ...  Now you can push that image to a repository for later use or to be shared. Keep in mind nothing is executing at this point ... you have just created an image which is just a chunk of code ... Sometime later you decide to launch an app using that image by doing

```
docker run -d -P --name cool-container-name  image-name
```

Above creates a container called cool-container-name which is an instantiation of the docker image ... the container is executing the code as outlined in your Dockerfile

So now its clear we can share either a Dockerfile or an image, however since a container is a chunk of executing code its not what gets shared